# True or false: any word recognized by a context-free grammar can also be recognized via rightmost derivation?

Tags: parsing, context-free-grammar

Suppose I have a context-free grammar

```
S -> ...
...
```

where "S" is a starting symbol. Let "w" be a word recognized by the grammar.  Is that true that w can also be recognized with rightmost derivation only?

Comment: How does a context-free grammar recognise a sentence? Presumably by deriving it. Is it possible that there is one or more derivations but none is rightmost? How?

Comment: Probably you are helping me to get the point, but I still don't get it. To answer your question,  I do not think it is possible that there is one or more derivations but none is rightmost. So what?

Comment: So if there is a derivation there is a rightmost derivation. So saying that a CFG derives a sentence is exactly the same as saying that it right-derives a sentence. If that doesn't answer your question, I don't understand the question.

Comment: If what you have in mind is that there is some way a grammar can recognise a sentence other than deriving it, I think you need to be clear what that would be. Grammars derive. You can build a parser based on a grammar, but that's a different thing.

Comment: You said "a CFG derives a sentence is exactly the same as saying that it right-derives a sentence." I think you mean that "a CFG derives a sentence implies that it right-derives a sentence in one of its parsing steps." Right?

Comment: No, a right-derivation is a complete derivation in which every step is rightmost. There are usually a large number of possible derivations, but exactly one of them is a rightmost derivation. So if there 8s a derivation of a sentence, there is a rightmost derivation; requiring that a derivation be rightmost does not restrict the set of sentences which can be derived. (You can consistently replace right with left and it's still true.)

Comment: I see. Thank you for helping. If you have time to compile your comments to an answer, I will certainly accept it, and probably other learners can also benefit from your answer.

Comment: It would be easier for me if I had a better idea of what the confusion was. But I'll see what I can do tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the confusion here revolves around the question of what it means for a grammar to "recognise a sentence".

In fact, context-free grammars are the representation of an operation which *generates* sentences, rather than recognises them. That is to say, each rule in the grammar defines a derivation step, which can be applied to a sentential form by replacing any one instance of the left-hand-side with the right-hand-side. If we form the closure of this operation starting with from the grammar's start symbol, then we have the set of sentential forms; the language of the grammar is the intersection of this set with the Kleene closure of the grammar's terminal alphabet.

(By "sentential form", we mean an element of the Kleene closure of the grammar's symbol alphabet, while "sentences" are restricted to elements in the Kleene closure of the terminal alphabet. This distinction is drawn from Knuth, I believe, but for now I'm still focusing on Noam Chomsky's groundbreaking paper *On Certain Formal Properties of Grammars*, written in 1959.)

As it happens, we can recursively enumerate the language (as a set). So we could "recognise" a sentence by starting the enumeration and waiting for the sentence to appear. This will work with any generative grammar, not just context-free grammars, but with Chomsky's unrestricted (Type 0) grammars, it has the problem that we never know when to give up waiting. (That is, it suffers from the same Halting Problem as general Turing Machines.) But with the restricted grammars we can produce an enumeration in which shorter sentences are generated before longer sentences, so we can definitely stop looking after we've enumerated all sentences of the length of the target sentence. (That's still not really satisfactory in practice, but it's great in theory. It's Theorem 3 in Chomsky's paper.) This is fundamentally the difference between a recursive set and a recursively enumerable set.

In practice, we want to create a parsing automaton based on the grammar, and more importantly we'd like the automaton to guarantee to work inside of well-defined time and space limits. And with Type 2 and Type 3 grammars, this is definitely possible (linear time and constant space for Type 3; polynomial time and space with exponent < 3 in the case of Type 2 grammars, and linear time and space in the case of a restricted subset of Type 2 grammars, called deterministic grammars.)

But let's go back to the question of what it means for the grammar to recognise (or generate) a sentence. Since the language is the closure of the derivation-step operator, it follows that every sentence in the language is the result of a finite sequence of derivation steps, starting with the start symbol. A sequence of derivation steps is called a derivation, and if there is a derivation of a sentence using a grammar, then the grammar is said to derive that sentence. That's as close as we're going to come to the concept of a grammar recognising a sentence.

Ideally, we'd like to reduce the noise created by the multitude of possible derivations of a sentence. Except for linear grammars, there will always be a lot of possible derivations because whenever there are two or more non-terminals in the sentential form, there are two or more possible derivation steps which can be applied, and in a context-free (Type 2) grammar the ones which "work" can be applied in any order. That's a simple way of thinking about what "context-free" means in this context. (I encourage any readers to try to make the previous statement more precise. I'm just trying to provide some intuitions here, not mathematical proofs.)

In Chomsky's paper, he shows how derivations can be viewed as traverses of a tree, where the tree actually expresses the syntactic structure of the derived sentence. Since we're actually interested in the tree and not the derivation sequence, we'd like to conflate all of the derivation sequences which are traverses of the same tree. And if there is only one such tree for any given sentence, then we can say that the grammar is unambiguous.

Unfortunately, as Chomsky also points out, Type 1 grammars are still too powerful to make this work, while Type 2 grammars are not powerful enough to represent the languages Chomsky was interested in (human languages, that is). But despite his frustration with this failure to define a useful category of grammars applicable to human language, his work was profoundly important in the development of modern formal language theory.

Now, let's restrict ourselves to Type 2 grammars, in which the order of application of derivation steps is irrelevant. In that case, we can use a very simple algorithm to associate a given parse tree with exactly one derivation sequence: we only allow the derivation sequence corresponding to a depth-first preorder right-to-left traverse. (That is, we visit the children right-to-left.) This corresponds to the rule that in a derivation sequence, each derivation step applies to the rightmost non-terminal in the sentential form. (It might seem more natural to do a left-to-right traverse, which would correspond to always expanding the leftmost non-terminal. That works, too, from the viewpoint of producing unique derivations from a parse tree. But it turns out to be less convenient.)

These insights come from another groundbreaking paper, Donald Knuth's *On the Translation of Languages from Left to Right* (1965).

So we should now be satisfied that the statements:

- Sentence Β is in the language of grammar G.
- G derives Β.
- G derives Β using only rightmost derivation steps.

all say the same thing. But along the way, we've also laid the foundation for several decades of parsing research.

It's pretty easy to find both of the papers I've cited here, and it's worth doing that because they are both pretty easy to read, and they contain a lot of the insights necessary to really understand LR parsing.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! Unfortunately, it reads intimidating for first-time learners of LR parsing. Sorry for being direct, but you only need to show S=>* w implies  S=>_{rm}* w. Right? Shouldn't it be a simple task (from the tone of your previous comments)?

Comment: Also, I appreciate the two references you have given.

Comment: @zell: my view is that it is basically obvious that if there is a derivation, there must be a rightmost derivation. So the problem must be not understanding that the only way a grammar can recognise a sentence is by deriving it. Perhaps I was wrong.

Comment: This is basically the problem with SO as used by students. The "encyclopedia of useful questions and answers" philosophy seems to me to be applicable to software development, where documentation is often at best an afterthought. Less so in academic environments, since students actually have comprehensive readable material in the form of textbooks, lecture notes, etc. What seems to be lacking is the one-to-one mentoring which was certainly an important aspect of my academic experience, brief though it was. I don't think SO can compensate...

Comment: After all, if the student only needs to crack open a textbook, why should I think I can provide a better answer? Writing textbooks is hard work, and usually remunerated. Otoh, I probably could do a reasonable job of engaging with a student's learning, but that's a process of dialog and dialog is essentially obviated by SO's structure. So, I accept that my answer treads ground unnecessary to simply answer a true-or-false question. But I think it has something of value for the student interested in the subject matter. I could be wrong about that, too.

Comment: You have your point. That is fine. BTW, I don't see it is "obvious that if there is a derivation, there must be a rightmost derivation". A derivation means a chain of production leading to a word. Thus, to prove the fact you took as granted, an algorithm must be constructed that rearranges the chain to another one in which all productions are rightmost. I do not think you have provided such an algorithm in your answer. But I respect your opinion as the problem being "obvious" for you and also appreciate the effort and time you have put into answering the question and helping others.

Comment: I think to prove what you called as obvious "if there is a derivation, there must be a rightmost derivation", you need to argue in this way: If there is a derivation, there must be a parsing tree. A parsing tree visited by the postfix manner produces a rightmost derivation.  My contention is that this proof needs some reflection.

Comment: @zell: Yes, it probably does require some reflection. What's more interesting, I think, is identifying the cases where it is not true. It is still true for a regular-right-hand-side extended CFG, for example. (That is, a CFG where the right-hand sides might contain alternation and Kleene star operators.) But it is not true for a context-sensitive grammar, because it's possible that a production with context cannot be applied until the context has been created by a further-right production. Hence Chomsky's frustration :-)

Comment: In any case, the insight that for a context-free grammar, a (equivalence class of) derivations can be represented as a parse tree is both interesting and important. Just presenting the simple inductive proof that if a derivation exists, a rightmost derivation exists (which is the canonical proof, I think) does not necessarily help.

Comment: Also, G.H. Hardy: https://i.imgur.com/X8yTMTH.png (About whom is the well-known joke about the maths professor who, during a lecture, says "This proposition is obvious..." and then stops, thinks, leaves the lecture hall, and returns 15 minutes later to resume the lecture with: "yes, it **is** obvious.")

Comment: OK, that was useful. I'll see if I can rewrite the answer to give a bit more prominence to that issue.